# How can I find the prototype of component class from class name in Angular and get the value of property defined in that class prototype?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-router, angular5

```
export class AppSample1Component {
  public propertyWithDefaultValue = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!';
}
```

Is it possible to access a component's class prototype in Angular?

For example (this one is not returning the value):

```
console.log(AppSample1Component.prototype.propertyWithDefaultValue);
```

How can I accces prototype of a class in route resolver function if it's possible?

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    const componentType = typeof route.component === 'string' ? route.component : route.component.name;
    console.log('Class name of the component: ', componentType);
    console.log('>>> I want to find the prototype of component class from ActivatedRouteSnapshot and get the value of "propertyWithDefaultValue" property of that class prototype in this section.');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all([
            this.getData()
        ]).then(
            () => {
                // Init component(s) after prefetch data, etc...
                resolve();
            },
            reject
            );
    });
}
```

You can check the [StackBlitz reproduction of the problem here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-1?file=app%2Fbase%2Fbase.service.ts).

---

**Edit**

I mentioned Angular because I want to learn if Angular has an internal method/property to find mapping of class properties metadata which allows me to access static properties of the class in router resolver method. 
Angular knows the route.component.name. So I thought it may have an internal place to find this kind of metadata.

```js
// Here's an example which shows a minimal use of OOP in my recent javascript projects
const myLib = {
    apply: function (obj, config) {
        if (obj && config && typeof config === 'object')
            for (var p in config)
                obj[p] = config[p];
        return obj;
    },
    extend: function (sc, bc) {
        var Fn = function () {};
        Fn.prototype = bc.prototype;
        var scpb = sc.prototype;
        var scp = sc.prototype = new Fn();
        scp.constructor = sc;
        if (bc.prototype.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor)
            bc.prototype.constructor = bc;
        myLib.apply(scp, scpb);
        sc.superclass = bc.prototype;
    }
};
myLib.textField = function (config) {

};
myLib.textField.prototype = {
    type: 'text'
};

myLib.numberField = function (config) {
 myLib.numberField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};
myLib.numberField.prototype = {
    type: 'number',
    min: 0,
    max: 9999
};
myLib.extend(myLib.numberField, myLib.textField);

const obj1 = new myLib.textField();
const obj2 = new myLib.numberField();

console.group('My old JS way');
console.log(obj1.type, obj2.type);
console.log(myLib.textField.prototype.max, myLib.numberField.prototype.max);
console.groupEnd();

// And here is a demonstration of typescript generated javascript.
// Compiled typescript code generates javascript class as something like below.
// Typescript places the properties to the beginning of the constructor, not to prototype.
// This is why it's not possible to access class prototype directly.
myLib.numberField2 = function () {
    this.type = 'number';
    this.min = 0;
    this.max = 9999;
    //constructor block begin
    //constructor block end
};
const obj3 = new myLib.numberField2();
console.group('Typescript compiled output demonstration');
console.log(obj3.max); // prints 9999

console.log(myLib.numberField2.prototype.max); 
// this prints "undefined" because max property doesn't exist before object creation
console.groupEnd();
```

Comment: Why do you think it will be transformed to `AppSample1Component.prototype.propertyWithDefaultValue`?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20AppSample1Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20propertyWithDefaultValue%20%3D%20'Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet!'%3B%0D%0A%7D

Comment: why do you need to set prototype of built-in class already? Extend it and set your custom variables in the custom child class.

Comment: @yurzui That syntax is the one which I was using to access a class prototype property in javascript. That's why I wrote it to show as an example. Not because I think it should transform into that form.

Comment: @omeralper Yes you're right. This is just for the demonstration for the problem. I'm trying to learn if it's possible to access that property while I just have the class name of the component in a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are asking "Is it possible to dynamically resolve a class given its name?"

Where you are trying to call this code and whether you are in Angular or not doesn't seem relevant to the question.

The general answer to the question is "no". Classes/modules don't necessarily have a unique name across your application. You can for example rename them when importing them (e.g. `import { LongClassName as LCN } from "./long-class-name";`). And there can be multiple classes with the same name.

Assuming you have imported all the classes you might need to resolve or are defining them in your current module, you could use `eval(classNameToResolve).prototype` to get the class prototype. Using `eval` is, however, strongly discouraged for security and performance reasons. And it will not work with all module bundlers or if you minify your code.

So, in short, no. Consider creating a mapping that allows you to do the lookup you need, e.g.

```
const ALL_MY_CLASSES = {
  ClassA: ClassA,
  ClassB: ClassB
}
```

Then you will be able to do the lookup using `ALL_MY_CLASSES[classNameToResolve].prototype`. You do, of course, need to add all the classes you might come across.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've prepared https://jsfiddle.net/hallilibrahim/wvm17c8d/ for an enhanced version of the question.